# How to export fluid animation 100% prebaked and import to UE4

Tags: animation, export, unreal-engine

I want to have a object lift out of water and have the water drop(drips) from the object, and doesn't need to be interact with, so it may be 100% pre-baked.

I made the animation in blender, but I can't seem to correctly export the fluid animation to UE4.8.

steps I did:

1. (Blender 2.74) make simple fluid simulation and bake it (using the Bake button in the Fluid domain Physics tab)
   (maybe I need to bake it another way after that?)
2. (Blender 2.74) Export it to FBX, well here are a lot of options, first im not sure wich version to use FBX 7.4 Binary or 6.1 ASCII Mainly I select version 7.4 and enable Apply Modifiers, Baked Animation, NLA Strips and All actions. (I tried many different options)
3. (UE4.8) Import FBX, and enable Import morph targets, import animations, import local transform. same goes here I tried a lot of different options.

   I hope someone can help me with this and put me in the right direction.

Comment: Due to the nature of fluid (bits splitting off and merging), each frame is actually a separate mesh. Not sure if blender really has a way to export this without writing some custom python or parsing the fluid cache files directly. And I don't know if/how mesh sequences are handled in UE.

Comment: Gandalf 3 is right.
Wanted to do the same thing, Searched the whole god darn internet. Found this guy's video. Ass got saved. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eariwFN_1_g Though it is not the most desirable way of doing it. But it sure keeps the boat afloat. Share this with all the people who are searching for this same problem. I have come across so many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really cannot. Fbx exporter won't take your fluid data, so only option you have is to export it as .obj sequence, which creates new mesh for each frame. Then in UE4 you most likely need to do some rather extensive programming to make your own custom animator to switch models per frames. Even if you would get this far it would be very likely that you run into performance issues unless your simulation resolution is very low.

Answer (score 5):

Some time ago I actually found a way to achieve this.

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YTDEdZovHbw) you will learn how to export .abc file from Blender properly, and then you can use [this add-on](https://github.com/unity3d-jp/AlembicForUnity) to simply import an .abc file into Unity.

[image: My Result]

Though the document is in Japanese, I think it's easy to follow.

By following these steps, you can get a nice animation outcome, just as in Blender.

Comment: Bless your soul dear friend! Now I finally understood why Adam team talked about Alembic importer.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the following method helped:

https://youtu.be/ZtWWHLHXWq4

Note: They only started supporting alembic files in both unity and blender in the recent months. Blender needs to be 2.81 and unity needs to be 2019.3.0a6 or higher and also have the alembic package installed in unity. Mine didn't work until I restarted my computer also.

Second note: Even after accomplishing this,  the amount of data the water animation took once it was in the game was humongous. I'm going back to the drawing board for a water fountain. Good luck!